# Assigning dates across dynamic overlapping periods in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a dataset with values logged over 15- or 60-minute periods for multiple days. The data includes a start date, start time, interval (15 or 60 minute logs), and the time of each count. However, the time for each count does not have the date associated with it and the dates are mixed across 24-hour periods (generally studies are performed for 48-hours but spanning 3 dates due to the start time.

i.e., the first study starts at 10:45, has a value every 15-minutes, and spans 2 days or 192 total 15-minute periods. HOWEVER, the logs start at midnight (00:00) so that the time is sequential. So for this first study, the periods from 00:00 to 10:30 are from the 2nd date, then from 10:45 to 23:45 the periods are from the 1st date, then the second 00:00 to 10:30 periods are from the 3rd date, and the final 10:45 to 23:45 periods are from the 2nd date again.

[image: Dates by time interval]

I need to define the date for each time. Further, as noted, the studies vary from 15-minute to 60-minute time intervals. Most are across 2 days (3 dates), but some are continuous across several days, and the start time itself changes for each study.

Honestly I'm not sure how to actually do most of these steps but my thought was along these lines (so far I've done step 1 in python...but that's it):

1. Use groupby to apply sequential order of time periods (for use in calculating the total length of a study & specifying which portions of a study to assign each date to...maybe)
2. Calculate number of periods in first day based on start time
3. Identify 1st row that matches the start time (day 1)
4. Assign day 1 date to 1st row that matched & all following until reaching the total periods of the first day
5. Calculate periods remaining for 24-hours from start time by subtracting out day 1 assigned periods.
6. Assign day 3 date to periods remaining for 24-hours from start time.
7. Assign day 2 date to any periods that do not have a date yet.

I've included a sample spreadsheet with a single study on it. It has the dates properly assigned but that was done manually & I have over 10k studies to do this for.

[Download Test Data from Single Study](https://netorg176945-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/ryan_heartlandmpo_org1/EZmntg5f1X5HoETBqP33h2oBZz5KzhakjqbiukZtTRV8Pg?e=ZaeYKb)

Answer (score 0):

May have been overcomplicating the problem since each day has a start and end date field as well (forgot about the end date). I ended up following these steps:

1. Flagging start times with a boolean comparing individual bins with the study (Head) time -- I know I don't have to create a field for this but I wanted the extra column to visualize where dates should change.
2. Assigning the starting date where boolean was true.
3. Forward filling within study groups to carry start date forward until the end of the day.
4. Assigning the ending date where values were still NaN.
5. For a complete datetime, I had to combine the study dates with the count times.

   ```
    # Calculate count time period without date
    df["Count_Time"] = df["START_TIME_Count"].dt.time
    df["Study_Start"] = df["START_TIME_Head"].dt.time

    # Identify start times
    df["Is_Start"] = df.Count_Time==df.Study_Start

    # Assign study start date
    df["Study_Date"] = np.nan
    df.loc[df.Is_Start==True, "Study_Date"] = df.START_DATE.dt.date

    # Forward fill start date within study day
    df["Study_Date"] = df.groupby("ID")["Study_Date"].transform(lambda x: x.ffill())

    # Assign end date where nan values still exist (should be everything before start time)
    df.loc[df.Study_Date.isna(), "Study_Date"] = df.END_DATE.dt.date

    # Combine study date & count time to create new datetime field for count
    df["Study_Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Study_Date.astype(str)+ " " + df.Count_Time.astype(str))
   ```